# Naming sections with docco/markdown?

Tags: coffeescript, markdown, docco

Using CoffeeScript and Docco, sections are created in the generated HTML which can then be used as links eg.

```
geometry.html#section-82
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to name these sections so it could instead be (for example):

```
geometry.html#vector
```

EDIT: It would seem this can be achieved by simply adding in the HTML manually:

```
**MARKDOWN**
# ## <section id='vector'>Vector:</section>
```

but is there any other, perhaps more elegant ways?

Comment: sounds like an excellent addition to the project, i recommend forking and creating pull request

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to find a repository for Markdown any where, I'm coming to the conclusion that it's not open source? And I'm feeling like this doesn't really belong in Docco, as docco doesn't actually do this sort of thing, it just interprets the markdown? Unless I'm mistaken? So not sure where it would go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the best way I can find to do this is as follows:

```
# ## <section id='vector'>Vector:</section>
```

It seems to work pretty well, wish I could add it to Markdown though.